# How can I sort all elements in a complex set of GKEntity?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, set, gameplay-kit

I have 4 classes like `D_Entity,P_Entity,T_Entity and O_Entity`,which have been defined as follows:

```
class D_Entity : GKEntity {
     var S_Comp : S_Component!
     .............
} 
class P_Entity : GKEntity {
     var S_Comp : S_Component!
     .............
} 
class T_Entity : GKEntity {
     var S_Comp : S_Component!
     .............
} 
class O_Entity : GKEntity {
     var S_Comp : S_Component!
     .............
}
```

Yes, all the four classes have the same member of `S_Comp`, which derives like:

```
    class S_Component : GKComponent {
     .............
    }
```

Then, I inserted all objects of `D_Entity,P_Entity,T_Entity and O_Entity` into a variable named `entities`, which is defined as:

```
var entities = Set <GKEntity>()
```

The problem is : I want to sort all elements in `entities` by the order of `S_Comp's position.y.` (`S_Comp` derives from `GKComponent` that has a member of `position`). In Swift 2, the example shows:

```
let ySortedEntities = entities.sort {
  let nodeA = $0.0.componentForClass(S_Component.self)!.node
  let nodeB = $0.1.componentForClass(S_Component.self)!.node
  return nodeA.position.y > nodeB.position.y
}
```

however, in Swift4 or 5, Xcode reported there is an error:

```
Value of type 'Set<GKEntity>' has no member 'sort'
```

I also found there is a function named `sorted` in `GKEntity`, but I don't know how to use it in such complex set.

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `sort` and `sorted` work almost identically. The only difference is that `sort` returns `Void` and edits the set in-place, whereas `sorted` returned a new copy that has been sorted, keeping the original intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 5 Set has no sort function

So, You can use Sorted function like this:

```
let ySortedEntities = entities.sorted(by: {
     let nodeA = $0.0.componentForClass(S_Component.self)!.node
     let nodeB = $0.1.componentForClass(S_Component.self)!.node
     return nodeA.position.y > nodeB.position.y
})
```